# Which explorer for local node

Tags: blockexplorer

I am currently running a full Tezos node and want to deploy a block explorer that is fed with my node RPC interface.

- tzkt.io seemed to be a good option but the front is not open-source
- tzstats.com used to be opensource but now the front is not maintained anymore

Do you know an alternative with a working front ?

Answer (score 1):

You have better call dev from baking bad team
https://github.com/baking-bad/bcd

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BCD is good when it comes to explore contracts but is not quite made to explore blocks and account transactions unfortunately